# Wordpress plugin not recognizing required file

Tags: php, wordpress

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Event_Logger.php");
global $Event_Logger;
$Event_Logger = new EventLogger();
```

Doing this displays a blank page and does not continue loading the page

The file on my server is located at `public_html/Event_Logger.php`

So I know I am doing this wrong `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns something I wasnt expecting so I am asking how do I get the top level of my site basically the folder public_html

Comment: If you could do that I'd gladly escape the planet. 
You can't do this because you can't read raw php code over http. It gets translated to static text representation. 

You could just put it into txt file and eval it, but .. you should not do it.

Comment: Don't use a URL: `require_once("Event_Logger.php");` or wherever is actually is.

Comment: What is stored in the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ? Does that path match with the location of your class file location ?

Comment: Not what I was looking for after echoing its value @Klamberext

Comment: in wordpress the constant `ABSPATH` contains the root path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (and shouldn't) include a file using URLs. You should use the path to the file locally, on the same server. If the plugin you're building lives on technologyforthefuture.org, then you can require it from the root path. If you're trying to include the file from an external website, that's not possible.

Comment: I have revised my question to accuratly depict where I am stuck

Comment: Have you tried this? require_once("./Event_Logger.php"); @JosephWilliamson